# Brightness changing even when auto brightness is disabled

Tags: display, dell, laptop, brightness

I have a new (July 2021) Dell XPS Laptop running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
I have turned OFF Automatic Brightness and manually set the brightness that I want.
But after rebooting often the brightness resets to near maximum brightness, and I have to manually change it back to the lower setting that I prefer.
How do I get it to stop doing this?

Comment: [This answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1391204/1222991) may help you with the brightness issue (See the first update) 

Comment: Won't the change In Update #1 hard-code the brightness to 80%?   I just want it to quit overriding the brightness that is manually set via the slider bars.

Answer (score 1):

One solution may be to set up a quick little script that will save the `brightness` value when the system shuts down, then configure the system to reload the value after booting. It's not perfect, but will do the job in a pinch.

Here's how you can set it up:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Create a file in `/etc/rc6.d`, which contains actions to be performed when shutting down. For the sake of this example, the file will be called `K99-save-brightness`:

   ```
   sudo {editor of choice} /etc/rc6.d/K99-save-brightness
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `{editor of choice}` with your editor of choice.</sup>
2. Copy the following into the file:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   cat /sys/class/backlight/nvidia_0/actual_brightness > /etc/acpi/backlight-brightness
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `nvidia_0` with the appropriate name that is found in `/sys/class/backlight`. It may be `intel_backlight`, `nvidia_0`, or something else entirely.</sup>
3. Save the file and ensure it is set to be executable:

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /etc/rc6.d/K99-save-brightness
   ```

Now every time your system shuts down, the value in `actual-brightness` will be written to the `/etc/acpi/backlight-brightness` file.

Next, you will need to run a little script after your system finishes booting. This can be accomplished via `crontab` like so:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Edit `crontab` as the super user:

   ```
   sudo crontab -e
   ```
2. Add this one-liner:

   ```
   @reboot (sleep 10 ; cat /etc/acpi/backlight-brightness > /sys/class/backlight/nvidia_0/brightness
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** The sleep value can be anything from `2`. When the value is less than `2`, there is a higher probability that the backlight setting will be overridden and reset to maximum. Of course, be sure to replace `nvidia_0` with the actual backlight device that you will be controlling.</sup>
3. Save the `crontab`
4. Reboot to test

This is certainly not an ideal solution, but it's one that does work on some of the notebooks that I help support at the day job. This should work on every modern version of Ubuntu from 18.04 to current.